# Responsive Image in fixed aspect ratio container in Firefox

Tags: firefox, aspect-ratio, border-box

I have a container with fixed aspect ratio.

I have an image with max-width and wax-height. The image needs to be contained within the bounds of the container.

I works fine in Chrome but fails in Firefox.

```
.responsive-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqkpszxz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set  `height:auto`,
usually the basics of making a block responsive is

```
  width:100%;
  height:auto
```

Comment: Edited the OP to clarify: the image needs to be contained within the container. In the example fiddle, the image would expand beyond the bottom border with your code.

Comment: usually an element is responsive to the left-right border;  you want it to shrink when it hits the top-bottom border? please set the fiddle correctly

Comment: I thought I did? The container has a width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

change this and it will work

```
.responsive-container {  
    height: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.responsive-container {  
    height:100%;//values changed
}
```

working EXAMPLE

http://jsfiddle.net/nqkpszxz/4/

Comment: This only leaves more room for the image by making the container bigger. The height of the container can't be set because it needs to keep the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday and put together [this JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eklingen/t4kd0p58/) with some inspiration from [this technique for CSS aspect ratios](http://siebennull.com/equal_width_height.html).

It looks like the aspect ratio for your .responsive-container class is working just fine, but that max-height and max-width on an img doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  That's what I ran into yesterday.

After looking around for a bit, I came to the do something that I normally wouldn't and decided to give a shot at inline styling:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/150x350');"></div>
```

Accompanied with the following CSS:

```
.image {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Seems to be working out so far for me.  Figured it was worth a share, even if it is a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the 'object-fit' property to the image element, besides setting it's height/max-height, width/max-width?

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/